# Formatting a Python generated CSV

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a web scraper in python.

I'd like to remove the blank rows from the generated csv and would like to add a header saying "Car make", "Car Model", "Price". and would also like to remove the [] from all the names in the generated csv

```
    imports go here...

    source = requests.get(' website link goes here...').text
    soup = bs(source, 'html.parser')

    csv_file = open('pyScraper_1.3_Export', 'w')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['brand_Names', 'Prices'])
    csv_file.close()

    #gives us the make and model of all cars
Names = []
Prices_Cars = []
for var1 in soup.find_all('h3', class_ = 'brandModelTitle'):
    car_Names = var1.text # var1.span.text
    test_Split = car_Names.split("\n")
    full_Names = test_Split[1:3]
    #make = test_Split[1:2]
    #model = test_Split[2:3]
    Names.append(full_Names)

    #prices
    for Prices in soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'f20 bold fieldPrice'):
        Prices = Prices.span.text
        Prices = re.sub("^\s+|\s+$", "",Prices, flags=re.UNICODE) # removing whitespace before the prices
        Prices_Cars.append(Prices)

    csv_file = open('pyScraper_1.3_Export.csv', 'a')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    i = 0
    while i < len(Prices_Cars):
        csv_writer.writerow([Names[i], Prices_Cars[i]])
        i = i + 1
    csv_file.close()

here is the screenshot of the generated csv

![][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Xw1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove additional newlines:

```
csv_file = open('pyScraper_1.3_Export.csv', 'a', newline='')
```

("If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with newline=''.", https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

To add headers:
you are actually adding headers, but to file named `pyScraper_1.3_Export` (note no `.csv` extension), this may be a mistype. Just change the code at about line 6 to

```
    csv_file = open('pyScraper_1.3_Export.csv', 'w', newline='')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(["Car make", "Car Model", "Price"])
    csv_file.close()
```

As for removing nested list, unpack `Names[i]` with `*` operator:

```
csv_writer.writerow([*Names[i], Prices_Cars[i]])
```